# Правильное сохранение изображений при их обновлении на сервере

Tags: java, android, bitmap, parse.com, изображения

В главном окне своего приложения я пытаюсь проверять наличие обновленного файла на сервере Parse.com.

Если файлов новых нет, Парс ничего не скачивает (это видно по закладке network в Android studio) - используется функция **getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback()**

Но при этом каждый раз, когда я нахожусь в главном окне приложения, и стартует загрузка обновлений, в приложении появляются огромные лаги (ужасно тормозит).
Видимо, это из-за того, что каждый раз приложение сохраняет и компрессирует файл (даже если он не был обновлен).

Как мне правильно построить обновление фотографий в моем приложении, чтобы **нагрузка на процессор была минимальна** (проблема именно в этом запросе, если его отключить, приложение работает лишь с незначительной нагрузкой на процессор)?

*Мой код сохранения:*

```
class download_images extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Images");
        query.setCachePolicy(ParseЗдравствуйте! 
Query.CachePolicy.CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK); // устанавливаю загрузку только если нет кеша
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {


            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    for (ParseObject parseObj : scoreList) {


                        try {
                            final ParseFile menuImage = (ParseFile) parseObj.get("mainImage"); //скачивание изображения главного меню
                            menuImage.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                public void done(byte[] data, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {

                                        try {

                                            Bitmap bitmap_menuImage;
                                            bitmap_menuImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                                            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
                                            File directory = cw.getDir("menuimage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                            if (!directory.exists()) {
                                                directory.mkdir();
                                            }
                                            File mypath = new File(directory, "menuimage.png");  // предполагаю, что тормозит именно из-за следующей части кода
                                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
                                            bitmap_menuImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                                            fos.close();

                                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                                            Log.e("LOG", e1.getMessage(), e1);
                                        }

                                    } else {
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e2) {
                            Log.e("LOG", e2.getMessage(), e2);

                        }


                    }

                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите сжатие и сохранение изображения в отдельный поток это раз. Это медленные операции и они не должны производиться в основном потоке. Что за либы Вы используете для организации загрузки файлов из сети не могу опознать, но думаю что раз там есть возможность кэширования, то должна быть и возможность узнать из кэша ли были взяты данные и соответственно сохранять картинку надо только если она не из кэша. Хотя мне не понятно на кой её вообще сохранять самостоятельно если она сохранена уже в кэше.

Ну а вообще существует столько замечательных библиотек для загрузки, кэширования и отображения картинок ([Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)), зачем вы какой то свой велосипед пишете?